# Resolving Secrets from a pinned Region with Serverless Framework at Resolution Mode 20210326

Tags: serverless-framework

Today I saw the deprecation warning for resolving region pinned SSM params & secrets by Serverless:

- previous: `ssm.<region>:<path>`
- new:  `ssm(<region>):<path>`

I've updated the variable resolving directly to the latest version via `variablesResolutionMode: 20210326`, but now this seems to not work anymore for secrets, but only SSM parameters.

Examples:

- `${ssm(eu-central-1):/some-ssm-param}` works fine.
- `${ssm(eu-central-1):/aws/reference/secretsmanager/some-secret}` doesn't.

Error message is not too helpful:

```
Invalid variable reference syntax for variable ssm(eu-central-1):/aws/reference/secretsmanager/some-secret.
You can only reference env vars, options, & files. You can check our docs for more info.
```

[Documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-using-aws-secrets-manager) does only give examples for retrieving secrets without the pinned region, but this worked before.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I ran into the same issue today, it seems it's a bug that needs to be reported in GitHub. By the way, the old way of referencing the region worked for me.